# Javascript hover with querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, hover, selectors-api

How do such a thing to work:

```
function getElements(attrib) {
    return document.querySelectorAll('[' + attrib + ']');
}

$(window).load(function () {
    $(".b1").hover(function () {

        $(this).className = 'x';

        var elements = getElements('code');

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i] == 'wow') {
                elements[i].className = 'blue';
            } else {
                    elements[i].className = 'red';
            }
        }

    }, function () {
        $(this).className = 'y';
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rc6Pq/10/

I would like hover to "BUTTON HOVER" and then show this elements with atributes "code" in different colors for "wow" and "lol".

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: And what's the problem with your code?

Comment: And why aren't you just using jQuery when you're using it for everything else ?

Comment: Basically, all of that code is a big syntax error, read the jQuery documentation and start small.

Comment: *"it is not working"* is a useless error description. If it was working, I imagine you wouldn't post here. Please be more specific and  [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: if you want version with pure js [look at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/rc6Pq/14/)

Answer (score 0):

What about this version:

```
function getElements(attrib) {
    return $('[' + attrib + ']');
}
$(window).load(function () {
    $(".b1").hover(function () {
        $(this).className = 'x';
        var elements = getElements('code');
        getElements('code').addClass('red').filter('[code="wow"]')
        .removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
    }, function () {
        $(this).className = 'y';
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rc6Pq/11/

or even better:

```
var elements = getElements('code'),
    wow = getElements('code').filter('[code="wow"]').addClass('blue');
elements.not(wow).addClass('red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rc6Pq/12/

Comment: I believe `$(this).className = 'x';` should be `this.className = 'x';`.